# prototype spring bean with global static variable

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I have a question that i have a spring-MVC based project.  In which there is a class containing all static variable which is accessible by all users.  All Bean are singleton, which creates problems when multiple users access application: the last user to modify the static variable at the same time a previous user is performing their task. So after last user comes the previous user's data, which overlaps with the data from the last user which creates conflict in the report.  I also user prototype bean, but I didn't find any solutions because of the static variable.  So anyone have solution related to this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First: use db, and save data there. If you restart your program all changes by users will be discarded.

Second: you tagged it corectly, since it is a question of concurency: make synchronization block, keep version, upon entrering synchronization block check if change is changing the latest version or previous one:
if you change latest commit - ok, if it's not: handle exception.

third: this smells bad desing. Are you sure you need all users MODIFY one parameter? Do you keep records of who and how modified it? Singletons are primarly used as read-only immutable objects that share information across whole application.

And forth: please, do not use static mutable variables. Seriously.